# Hello i want to scrape a link with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

hello i have worked with selenium for a week now, but i never encountered this sor t of problem.. 
In this given website https://xangle.io/project/list when I click on any row of the first column it takes to me to a different page. I want to scrape that link to the new page. But when ever I try to inspect the element to find the link I dont see any "href" or any sort of link on the element. I have given a screenshot of the html.. [image: screenshot]
I didnt know what to do or what to write in the code.. That is why I couldnot attach any sample codes. Please could you help me find what is wrong? or what should i do in such situations.. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
    driver.get('https://xangle.io/project/list')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Tezos')]"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

[image]

Comment: sure i would do that, actually i didnt want to click.. I want to scrape the url

Comment: sorry didnt understand you

Comment: I want to scrape this URL for each of the elements in the table

Comment: why cant i post a picture in the comment

Comment: I want to scrape the link that is generated when you click the "Tezos" span

Comment: thank you, it solves for the "Tezos".. but you see there are other similar spans below tezos in the table right? i want to do this for all of them. Could you help me

Comment: it doesnot work, i should have checked it before